# Can't see procedure in SQL profiler (RPC:Complited event)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I call stored procedure 'Get_Units' from C# app. It executes successfully, but I can't see that procedure in SQL profiler (Need to see it with RCP:Complited event because I need Read/Writes statistics)

C# code to execute stored procedures:

```
    public string ExecSpReturnTime(string connectionString, string code)
    {
        long execTime = 0;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.StatisticsEnabled = true;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(code, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            var stats = connection.RetrieveStatistics();
            execTime = (long)stats["ExecutionTime"];
        }
        return execTime.ToString();
    }
```

What SQL Server Profiler shows (no column filters are applied):

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It will only appear as an `RPC:Completed` event if it's actually issued as an RPC call. The code above does not set `CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, so it will only appear as a regular SQL batch (`SQL:BatchCompleted`).

Comment: Your code will generate a `Batch:Completed` event. An RPC will be issued only if you set the command type to stored procedure or add parameters to the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set CommandType to StoredProcedure and SQL profiler now shows my procedure! Thank you kindly, Jeroen Mostert